# Prove "If $B \subseteq A_k$, for all $k\in I$, then $B \subseteq \bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$" and other similar statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

"$\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i \subseteq A_k$, for all $k\in I$. If $B \subseteq A_k$, for all $k\in I$, then $B \subseteq \bigcap_{i\in I} A_i.$"

*Proof.* Let $k_{0}$ be an arbitrary element of $I$. Suppose $x\in B$, by hypothesis $x\in A_{k_0}$. Note that $k_0$ is an arbitrary element of $I$, then $x\in A_{k}$, for all $k\in I.$ Therefore $x\in \bigcap_{i\in I} A_i. \Box$

"$A_k \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$, for all $k\in I$. If $A_k \subseteq B$, for all $k\in I$, then $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i \subseteq B$."

*Proof.* Suppose $x\in \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$, then $x\in A_i$, for at least one $i\in I$. Let $k_0\in I$ such that $x\in A_{k_0}$. Given that $x\in A_{k_0}$, and $A_k \subseteq B$, for all $k\in I$, then $x\in B$. Hence $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i \subseteq B. \Box$

Are my proofs correct? English is not my native language, if there's something wrong with my use of the language (inside the proof) I'd like to now it. Thank you!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Hello, @Math_QED. I have a question related to my second proof. Do you think replacing "Let $k_0\in I$ such that $x\in A_{k_0}$" with "Let $k_0\in I$, thus $x\in x_{k_0}$" (taking for granted $k_0$ is an arbitrary element of $I$) would be acceptable?

Comment: This seems weird. I added an answer so you see how I would prove it.

Comment: Btw, good job that you wrote your first post in such high quality (good formatting etc.) +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proofs both are correct. What looks a little strange (but not entirely wrong), is that you choose $k_0 \in I$.

I will prove both statements now as I would do it. You will notice both proofs are nearly exactly the same as yours are.

1) Let $x\in B$. Then, we know that $x \in A_k $ for all $k \in I$. Therefore, $x \in \bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$ (if an element is in all sets $A_i$, then certainly in their intersection). We conclude that $B \subset \bigcap_{i\in I} A_i.\quad\triangle$

2) Let $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I}A_i$ Then, there exists a $l \in I$ such that $x \in A_l$ (if an element is in a union, then the element is certainly in one of the sets forming the union). Because $A_l \subset B$ (as this is true for all sets $A_k$, certainly true for the specific set $A_l$), we find that $x \in B$. Hence, $\bigcup_{i \in I}A_i \subset B.\quad\triangle$

The technique is always the same. If you want to show that $A \subset B$,take an element $a \in A$ and show $a \in B$.