# How to prove that subset of sets is also a subset of their intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say we have a set $X$ which contains some sets $X = \{A_1, A_2, ...\}$.

Now, let's define their intersection; $A = A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ...$ How to prove that if $A' \subseteq A_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$, namely if $A'$ is a subset of every element of $X$, that $A' \subseteq A$?

I am learning about Dedekind's cuts so I need this piece of information to conclude that any subset of set of all cuts bounded below has an infimum, and thus we have a set of real numbers.

Thank you.

Comment: Here is a related question - it is proof-verification questions, but it might be useful anyway: [Prove "If $B \subseteq A_k$, for all $k\in I$, then $B \subseteq \bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$" and other similar statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2233585)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A' \subseteq A_{i} \implies \forall a\in A', a\in A_{i}$. If that's true $\forall i\in\mathbb{N}$ then $$\forall a\in A', a\in A_1\cap A_2....=A \implies A'\subseteq A$$

Comment: Thanks, that's exatcly what I neeeded.